# Write a function longestWord() which receives a list of words, then returns the longest word ending with "ion"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

Write a function longestWord() which receives a list of words, then returns the longest word ending with "ion".

This is what i got so far:

```
def longest(listTest):
  word_len = [] 
  for n in listTest: 
    word_len.append((len(n), n)) 
    word_len.sort() 
  return word_len[-1][1] 

print(longest(["ration","hello","exclamation"]))
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi, this is what i got so far 
def longest(listTest):
    word_len = []
    for n in listTest:
        word_len.append((len(n), n))
    word_len.sort()
    return word_len[-1][1]

print(longest(["ration","hello","exclamation"]))

Comment: This is the 1st time i use this so i don't know why is written in the same line

Comment: I edited your question, pls latter on, try to more elaborate about your problem: what you have tried, expected input, expected output ..etc.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome , have look over this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
longestWord = max([i for i in listTest if i.endswith("ion")], key=len)
print(longestWord)
```

Comment: No need for the lambda, just pass `len`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: listTest
Out[9]: ['ration', 'hello', 'exclamation']

In [10]: def longest(lst):
    ...:     return sorted([(len(i),i) for i in lst if i.endswith("ion")], key=lambda x:x[0])[-1][1]
    ...:

In [11]: longest(listTest)
Out[11]: 'exclamation'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function accomplishes this with list comprehension and the `max` function. You can also pass any suffix you like here.

```py
def longest(words, suffix="ion"):
    # Filter the passed words
    words_with_suffix = [w for w in words if w.endswith(suffix)]

    # Return the longest word in the filtered list
    return max(words_with_suffix, key=len)


list_test = ["ration","hello","exclamation"]

print(longest(list_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
longest = ''
for word in listTest:
    if word.endswith('ion') && (longest.size() < word.size() ):
         longest= word

print(longest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers so far seem to be able to handle the edge case of two different words having the same length (and ending in "ion"), here is my simple approach:

```
filteredWords = [word for word in listTest if word.endswith("ion")]
wordLenghts = [len(word) for word in filteredWords]
maxLength = max(wordLenghts)
longestWordsIndices = [i for i, j in enumerate(wordLenghts) if j == maxLength]

print( [filteredWords[w] for w in longestWordsIndices] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list where you can have all the strings that are ending with 'ion', then you can sort the list to get the `longest word` ending with 'ion'.

In the given code, I have used `Bubble sort` to sort the list considering the list to be small, if you have to deal with larger data for this then I will suggest you, use a better sorting algorithm since Bubble sort performance is O(n^2).

```
s = ["ration","hello", "test", 'why', 'call', 'ion', "exclamation", 'cation', 'anion']
word = []
for i in s:
    if i.endswith('ion'):
        word.append(i)

#using bubble sort considering the list is small
for i in range(len(word) - 1):
    for j in range(len(word) - (i+1)):
        if len(word[j]) < len(word[j+1]):
            temp = word[j]
            word[j] = word[j+1]
            word[j+1] = temp

print(word[0])  #the longest word
```